# FInd all intersections of xy data point graph with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, intersection, points

I am analyzing data from cyclic tensile tests. As input are used *huge* lists of x and y values.
To describe if the material hardens or softens, I need to get the blue slope of each cycle loop.

[image: tensile_test]

[image: slope]

Getting the lower point of slope is child festival, but the upper one, that is the challenge.

[image: the_challenge]

I have made this approach so far, slicing out the loops with few points below local maximum of each loop and making the red lines from *hardnumbered* count of points. Aproximation of red lines is made by `poly1d(polyfit(x1,x2,1))` and `fsolve` is used then to get the intersection point. However it does not works always correctly, because the distribution of points is not always the same.

[image]

The problem is how to *correctly define the interval* of two (red) intersecting lines. In the picture above are 3 experiments together with averaged slope. I spent few days trying to find 4 closest points for each loop deciding this is not the best approach. And finally, I ended here at stackowerflow.

Desired output is list with approximate coordinates of intersection points - if you want to play, [here](http://bit.ly/1cgP7A0) are data for the curve (0,[[xvals],[yvals]]). Theese can be easily read with

```
import csv
import sys
csv. field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)     

csvfile = 'data.csv'
tc_data = {}
for key, val in csv.reader(open(csvfile, "r")):
    tc_data[key] = val
for key in tc_data:
  tc = eval(tc_data[key])

x = tc[0]
y = tc[1]
```

Comment: Neither of your links is working for me.

Comment: I wonder how you achieved the zoom-in effect with matplotlib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a little overkill, but the proper way to find your intersection point, once you have split up your curve into chunks, is to see if any segment from the first chunk intersects with any segment from the second chunk.

I am going to make myself some easy data, a piece of a [prolate cycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProlateCycloid.html), and am going to find places where the y-coordinate flips from increasing to decreasing similarly to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909007/110026):

```
a, b = 1, 2
phi = np.linspace(3, 10, 100)
x = a*phi - b*np.sin(phi)
y = a - b*np.cos(phi)
y_growth_flips = np.where(np.diff(np.diff(y) > 0))[0] + 1

plt.plot(x, y, 'rx')
plt.plot(x[y_growth_flips], y[y_growth_flips], 'bo')
plt.axis([2, 12, -1.5, 3.5])
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you have two segments, one going from point `P0` to `P1`, and another going from point `Q0` to `Q1`, you can find their intersection point by solving the vector equation `P0 + s*(P1-P0) = Q0 + t*(Q1-Q0)`, and the two segments actually do intersect if both `s` and `t` are in `[0, 1]`. Trying this out for all segments:

```
x_down = x[y_growth_flips[0]:y_growth_flips[1]+1]
y_down = y[y_growth_flips[0]:y_growth_flips[1]+1]
x_up = x[y_growth_flips[1]:y_growth_flips[2]+1]
y_up = y[y_growth_flips[1]:y_growth_flips[2]+1]

def find_intersect(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up):
    for j in xrange(len(x_down)-1):
        p0 = np.array([x_down[j], y_down[j]])
        p1 = np.array([x_down[j+1], y_down[j+1]])
        for k in xrange(len(x_up)-1):
            q0 = np.array([x_up[k], y_up[k]])
            q1 = np.array([x_up[k+1], y_up[k+1]])
            params = np.linalg.solve(np.column_stack((p1-p0, q0-q1)),
                                     q0-p0)
            if np.all((params >= 0) & (params <= 1)):
                return p0 + params[0]*(p1 - p0)

>>> find_intersect(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up)
array([ 6.28302264,  1.63658676])

crossing_point = find_intersect(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up)
plt.plot(crossing_point[0], crossing_point[1], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]

On my system, this can handle about 20 intersections per second, which is not superfast, but probably enough to analyze graphs every now and then. You may be able to spped things up by vectorizing solution of the 2x2 linear systems:

```
def find_intersect_vec(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up):
    p = np.column_stack((x_down, y_down))
    q = np.column_stack((x_up, y_up))
    p0, p1, q0, q1 = p[:-1], p[1:], q[:-1], q[1:]
    rhs = q0 - p0[:, np.newaxis, :]
    mat = np.empty((len(p0), len(q0), 2, 2))
    mat[..., 0] = (p1 - p0)[:, np.newaxis]
    mat[..., 1] = q0 - q1
    mat_inv = -mat.copy()
    mat_inv[..., 0, 0] = mat[..., 1, 1]
    mat_inv[..., 1, 1] = mat[..., 0, 0]
    det = mat[..., 0, 0] * mat[..., 1, 1] - mat[..., 0, 1] * mat[..., 1, 0]
    mat_inv /= det[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    import numpy.core.umath_tests as ut
    params = ut.matrix_multiply(mat_inv, rhs[..., np.newaxis])
    intersection = np.all((params >= 0) & (params <= 1), axis=(-1, -2))
    p0_s = params[intersection, 0, :] * mat[intersection, :, 0]
    return p0_s + p0[np.where(intersection)[0]]
```

Yes, it's messy, but it works, and does so x100 times faster:

```
find_intersect(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up)
Out[67]: array([ 6.28302264,  1.63658676])

find_intersect_vec(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up)
Out[68]: array([[ 6.28302264,  1.63658676]])

%timeit find_intersect(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up)
10 loops, best of 3: 66.1 ms per loop

%timeit find_intersect_vec(x_down, y_down, x_up, y_up)
1000 loops, best of 3: 375 us per loop
```

Comment: Jaime, I owe you crate of beer. Send me your address and I will ship it right away!

Comment: I am getting TypeError: int is required at line `intersection = np.all((params >= 0) & (params <= 1), axis=(-1, -2))` of `find_intersect_vec` with your prolate cycloid example data.

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? Multiple axis where introduced in 1.7, if you are using an earlier version you may have to nest two calls to `np.all`, I think `intersection = np.all(np.all((params >= 0) & (params <= 1), axis=-1), axis=-1)` should do the same in 1.6.

Comment: You are right again, I should point it out. Well I have learned a lot of things past two days. Thanks to you!

Comment: Awesome solution! May I ask why sometimes find_intersect() raises Singular Matrix Exception? I now simply ignore this exception, the algorithm succeeds in finding all the intersections. But I think simply ignore it is inproper.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng I believe if there is a singular matrix exception it would be because the two lines we are trying to intersect are parallel, which means that the `(params >= 0) & (params <= 1)` condition would not be fulfilled anyway, so you may very well ignore that iteration.

Comment: Oh I see. So simply use a try...exception pass block would be good enough. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this very simply by using the interp1d function from scipy to resample the y-values of all your lines at the same x values.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html